# Scribe Tattoo Feat - How does it work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am very new to psionics. I have never used it in D&D, and only recently discovered it in Pathfinder. However, the Scribe Tattoo feat is still a bit of a mystery to me. I know I can only scribe tattoo's of 3rd level and lower, but everything else is still a bit hazy. To make my questions easier, I will use the power Metamorphosis (Minor) as the one I want to tattoo.

1. Is this a legal power to tattoo? The feat says "targets one or more creatures". With this power, you are the target creature, so it is legal, right?
2. The power states I can choose one option from either Enhancement Menu A or Abilities Menu A. Do I have to make this choice when I scribe the tattoo, or can I make it when I invoke the tattoo?
3. By paying two more Power Points, I may choose one option from Enhancement Menu A as well as one option from Abilities Menu A. May I scribe the tattoo to allow me to choose like this, or am I limited to the base version (only one option total from both menu's)?
4. When I scribe the tattoo, do I pay the Power Point cost as part of the creation of the tattoo? And if so, do I pay the extra cost for Point 3 above (should Point 3 be allowed)?

Hopefully by getting answers to the above, I will understand the Scribe Tattoo feat better, but knowing myself I will probably have a another bunch of questions popping into my head, so if you know of anything important which I may have neglected to ask, please be as kind as to add that information in your answer as well! Thanks for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psionics is always a confusing topic, but hopefully we'll be able to help out a bit for you!

Target:Self is a way to prevent your self-buffing spells to be applied to anyone else.  In much the same way, you wouldn't be able to scribe this power to anyone else to benefit from.

According to the [Scribe Tattoo Feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/scribe-tattoo-item-creation)

> When you create a psionic tattoo, you make any choices that you would normally make when manifesting the power. When its wearer physically activates the tattoo, the wearer is the target of the power.

This shows that any choices you want to make, including expending extra Power Points must be decided when you create the tattoo, using your currently available power points and expending them into the tattoo.

One thing to remember, these tattoo's are a one-time use only.  Check out this quote from the [Psionic Tattoo Item Page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psionic-tattoos)

> Activation: A psionic tattoo produces its effect when touched by its wearer and willed to do so. This activity, called “tapping” the tattoo, is a standard action that provokes attacks of opportunity. A psionic tattoo fades away after use.

Comment: So in my example above, can my character scribe the Metamorphosis (Minor) tattoo on himself, then transfer it to a companion? This line seems to suggest it is possible: "As a standard action, the wearer can will the tattoo to move to a different part of his body or onto the skin of any willing (or unconscious) living creature he touches."

Comment: @Sam I have seen a lot, lot of argue about self-buffs transfered to others. Some say it cannot be done. Some says it can be done but tattoo won't work. Some say it will work all right. But that's the matter for another question, isn't it?